# ripgrep: print only filenames matching pattern

Tags: search, ripgrep

Using [ripgrep (`rg`)](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep), can I print only the filenames which match a given pattern?

There are two separate things I'm trying to do:

1. Match the pattern to the pathname itself (like `ag -g pattern`)
2. Match the pattern to the contents of the file and print only the filename

I can't work out how to do either one.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

1. Print only the filename where the contents match:

   ```bsh
   rg -l regex
   # OR: long-option form
   rg --files-with-matches regex
   ```
2. Print only the directory entries (filenames) which match the given pattern under `<directory>`:

   ```bsh
   rg -g '*glob*' --files <directory>
   ```

   The `-g` specifies a glob whose rules match [`.gitignore` patterns](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format).

   Precede a glob with a `!` to exclude it.

   Use `--iglob` instead of `-g` for a case-insensitive glob.

   `--files` prints each file that would be searched without actually performing the search.

---

A less efficient way to do (2) would be:

```bsh
rg -lg '*pattern*' . <directory>
```

The `.` says to match any character inside the files (so it won't match on empty files).

Comment: If you want at most one line per file, but still want to see the contents of the matching line, you can use `--max-count 1`

Comment: How to make the glob pattern match the relative path and not only the file name?